# Can I create a new Google Keep note from Chrome's omnibox?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-keep

[Chrome's omnibox features](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/11-quick-tricks-to-become-a-chrome-omnibox-power-user/) are really great, e.g. to [create a new Google Calendar event](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/add-google-calendar-event-using-omnibox/).

Is someone aware of any possibility to create a new Google Keep note from the omnibox?

Comment: If you can find a URL that will create a new note then you can probably use the same method. However, Keep seems to be a single page/AJAX app and doesn't change the URL (except when displaying a note). As a workaround you could create a "search engine" that simply opens Keep. The cursor is then positioned in the "New note" box.

Comment: Thank you @w3dk! So basically creating a bookmark is the only possible workaround. What a bummer.

Comment: Well, you could use the above method so that you just type `keep` in the omnibox to be redirected to the Google Keep site?

Comment: Tangentially related: Keep is a valid target for the "Note to self" voice command on Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can write [keep.new](https://keep.new) to create a new note. Make sure that:

1. You are logged in with your Google Account
2. You are online

You can even use these other links:

- [doc.new](https://doc.new) / [sheet.new](https://sheet.new) / [slide.new](https://slide.new) to create a new Google Document / Spreadsheet / Slide;
- [cal.new](https://cal.new) to create a new Google Calendar event...

Explore all the .new shortcuts on [whats.new](https://whats.new/)